# jQuery dialog issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

We have an application that has a very large Administration piece. We are using jQuery dialogs on a few of the pages that contain cascading dropdowns (data driven using ajax\json) and jQuery date pickers. We are having a lot of issues with this.

I have been googling around for a few weeks and I have discovered that many developers are experiencing similar problems. I have found a lot of suggestions but none of them seem to resolve all the issues. The issues we have all come on the second time a user navigates to a page containing one of these dialogs and this seem to be a recurring theme with a lot of complaints.

Our particular issues are that the date picker in disabled on the second load (more specifically the textbox that the date picker is assigned to).  Some of the cascading dropdowns do not set the selected value on the second page load for and edit function. We are on `jQuery 1.7.2` and `jQuery UI 1.8.18`. Has anyone encountering these same issues found a solution?

** NEW INFO - I have discovered that this is an IE 9 issue only. Everything works fine in Firefox and IE 8 - trying to come up with a solution for that **

Comment: I can understand a bit your problem, but if you post a JsFiddle, would be nice and more easy to understand. Also, will be an easy way to give you some suggestions, if I understand your problem and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Would love to post a JsFiddle but company policy prevents me from posting our code. If you have any specific chunks I could post similar code that I change around a little but with same operation for yo to look at.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer you, I'm in the office and it was eating time =D Don't worry, I know some companies force to their employers to don't post programming codes. Well, correct me if I'm wrong, please. You have an application that when you click a button, or something like that, you open a jQuery dialog that contains a title, close button (top right corner) and a "submenu" that is composed by some dropdowns and datepickers, right?

Comment: Correct - it has dropdowns and a date picker. It all works fine the first time. The second time the dialog opens is when the issues occur. The dropdowns load the values correctly but the selected value does not get set (edit function) and the date picker text box is disabled. You see the calendar pop up when clicking the date picker icon but no dates can be selected as the text box is disabled.

Comment: Did you tried this: `onClose: function() {$(this).dialog('destroy');$(this).remove();}`? Seems like an "invisible" dialog, the first one, is not removed and appears at the front, not allowing you to select any option.

Comment: I have tried it with the 'destroy' only and it did not help. I can try adding the call to 'remove' and see if it helps - will let you know.

Comment: Well - it solves my original problem but creates a new one. If they go to re edit an item without reloading the page the html for the dialog is now gone and the data cannot be rebound to it or retrieved from it.

Comment: I can suggest you to save your data from dialog into a global Object into your JavaScript and reload the data every time you open the dialog. Initially, your object must be empty, then your fields, etc. will be empty. If it is not a problem for you, I think you can use it as trick, if you dont have anything else.

Comment: I'm not understanding. The HTML that is the dialog is hardcoded on the page - it is a <div> with an id that the jQuery dialog function selects. The data that gets bound to those HTML elements is not lost - it is the HTML elements that are lost.

Comment: Before you destroy the elements inside the div using `$(this).remove();`, save all values that you want to be shown if you reedit your dialog into a JavaScript Object, for example. Then, after load it next time, set for each element his value.

Comment: The values for each element of the edit dialog do already get set each time before the dialog is opened. The elements are not available to set a value to after the destroy and also this seems very kludgy - one should not have to go through this just to open a dialog after re navigating to the page again.

Comment: Seems the end for me here u.u I'm sorry, but I think I can't help you any more. We cant discuss this without demos, etc. to show some examples. Also, in my case, every time I go through a dialog, like click link and open a form, if I have to set some information into his elements, It does an ajax call to server, retrieve data and loads it into my form elements. When I finish, into the `close` property, I set a function with `.dialog('destroy');` and `.remove();` (i.e.) Register form. Hope it helps. Sorry, but I can't help you :(

Comment: I appreciate all the help you gave and I am pretty much doing the same thing. Ajax call to get json data to set the values for the dialog items then open. With all the similar issues that I see people having I have to think that the jQuery dialog is somewhat buggy.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe is bugged, developers can't do perfect things :P Good luck with your search about the issue

Comment: Discovered this is only and issue in IE 9 - works in IE 8 and Firefox.

Comment: hahahaha are you for real? xD Well, always the same is who gives the errors ;) Take care working with it when developing. For me, is the worst web browser I've ever seen.

Comment: I agree - I hate IE but forced to support it -